# Как разместить в шапке сайта картинку справа а текст слева?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div{
            background: gray;
            height: 100px; 
            text-align: right;                
        }
        p2{
            display: inline-block;
            background: orange;
            color: aliceblue;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 40px 40px 60px 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;           
        }           
        img{                
            margin-left: 30px ;                
        }
        p3{
            margin: 10px 30px 10px 12px;
            color: aliceblue;
        }
        p4,p5{
            color: aliceblue;
            margin: 60px 30px 10px 12px;            
        }
        .logo{
            height: 80px;
            width: 158px;
            margin-right:400px;
        }
        div2{
            height:  100px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        h1{
            height: 120px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/logo.png" alt="">
        <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/phone icon.png" alt=""><p3>0 800 337 146</p3>
        <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/Skype icon.png" alt=""><p4>support_cbs</p4>
        <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/telegram icon.png" alt=""><p5>cbs_support</p5>
   
        <p2>Заказать консультацию</p2> 
    </div>
    <div2>
        <h1></h1>
    </div2>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Я только учусь html разметке, и мне дали задание [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все получается хорошо именно до того момента, когда я добавляю лого в левую часть. Вот так до добавление картинки слева[image: введите сюда описание изображения] А вот уже после добавления[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Само лого можно разместить ближе к левому краю но вот информация с правой части никак не центрируется по вертикали. Прилагаю код и надеюсь на помощь(картинки не грузит потому что они у меня на компе)

Answer (score 1):

Объединяйте необходимые элементы в группы. И советую почитать про `flex-box`, он Вам не раз спасёт положение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.head {
  background: gray;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

p2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 40px 40px 60px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

img {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

p3 {
  margin: 10px 30px 10px 12px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

p4,
p5 {
  color: aliceblue;
  margin: 60px 30px 10px 12px;
}

.logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 158px;
  margin-right: 400px;
}

div2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="head-logo">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/99DPhQC/logo.jpg" alt="logo" border="0">
    </div>
    <div class="head-cont">
      <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/phone icon.png" alt="">
      <p3>0 800 337 146</p3>
      <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/Skype icon.png" alt="">
      <p4>support_cbs</p4>
      <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/telegram icon.png" alt="">
      <p5>cbs_support</p5>

      <p2>Заказать консультацию</p2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div2>
    <h1></h1>

  </div2>

</body>

</html>
```

Вариант без `flex-box`:

```css
.head {
  background: gray;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.head>div {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.head-logo {
  float: left;
}

.head-cont {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

p2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 40px 40px 60px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

img {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

p3 {
  margin: 10px 30px 10px 12px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

p4,
p5 {
  color: aliceblue;
  margin: 60px 30px 10px 12px;
}

.logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 158px;
  margin-right: 400px;
}

div2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="head-logo">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/99DPhQC/logo.jpg" alt="logo" border="0">
    </div>
    <div class="head-cont">
      <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/phone icon.png" alt="">
      <p3>0 800 337 146</p3>
      <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/Skype icon.png" alt="">
      <p4>support_cbs</p4>
      <img src="/html-css-starter-materials/006/DZ/images/telegram icon.png" alt="">
      <p5>cbs_support</p5>

      <p2>Заказать консультацию</p2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div2>
    <h1></h1>

  </div2>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Можно ли выполнить данное задание не используя флекс бокс? просто у меня этот урок следующий, я ещё его не проходил

Comment: Есть такой вариант, это ```grid```. Шутка, это видимо тоже ещё только впереди, поэтому рискну предположить, что Вам нужен вариант через свойство ```float```. Это очень старый метод, им не пользуется уже давненько. Скорее всего из-за того, что выравнивать не просто. Я добавил второй вариант в свой ответ, можете посмотреть